# Convert Base Class to Subclass in Ruby

Tags: ruby

in ruby

```
class A
  @x = 1
  @y = 2
  attr_accessor :x, :y
end

class B < A
  @z = 3
  attr_accessor :z
end

a = A.new
b = B.new
```

[1] convert an instance of A (a) to B? without losing any A's member values
in c++ there would be static_cast, reinterpret_cast, "convert" operator, etc.. how to do this on ruby? (is there any shortcut), for example

```
b = a.convert_to B
# b.x = 1
# b.y = 2
# b.z = 3
```

[2] how to overwrite each inherited data member values of B (b) instance using a's value if there's many data members inherited? (is there a built in method or shortcut to do this?) for example

```
a.x = 1
a.y = 2

b.x = 3
b.y = 4
b.z = 6

b.overwrite_all_inherited_method_from a
# b.x = 1
# b.y = 2
# b.z = 6
```

Comment: That's some bad OOP right there, if you ask me.

Comment: which part is bad? :| thank you in advance

Comment: The downcasting part. I have yet to see a valid need for this.

Comment: so, it is better to use aggregation/composition?

Comment: It depends on a problem

Comment: for example, i have a Slide (name, description, type), 
SlideWithVideo (+videos[] --> width, height, duration, format, path), SlideWithPicture (+picture --> width, height, format, path) and SlideWithQuestions (+question --> many things mostly text)

Comment: at certain point, a slide need to be converted to any of it's subclass, and can be copied (as template) to another subclass

Comment: what if i want to inherit Array to add some method but only for certain scope..

Comment: What do you mean, 'certain scope'?

Comment: well, i don't want to pollute whole array class with my function of course, so i need to subclass an array class, and convert array to my custom array, so that my methods only work on certain method, class or module..

Comment: There's a proposed feature in ruby 2.0 that does what you want: enhance the `Array` class but only in certain scopes, which have to opt-in. After some intense debates, the feature was decided to remain in "experimental" state, until remaining design questions are cleared. It's called "refinements", you can google if you're interested. In the meanwhile, I think your best bet is to list the methods you want to copy and implement "convert-constructors" manually. I would do just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smth like that?

```
class A
  attr_accessor :x, :y

  def copy other
    other.instance_variables.each do |v| 
      instance_variable_set v, other.instance_variable_get(v)
    end
  end
end

class B < A
  attr_accessor :z
end

a = A.new
a.x = 1
a.y = 2

b = B.new
b.z = 3

puts a.inspect, b.inspect
#<A:0x0000010127f3d8 @x=1, @y=2>
#<B:0x0000010127f3b0 @z=3>

b.copy a

puts a.inspect, b.inspect
#<A:0x0000010127f3d8 @x=1, @y=2>
#<B:0x0000010127f3b0 @z=3, @x=1, @y=2>
```